# Tilde prefix returns invalid home directory

Tags: home-directory, tilde-expansion

I am trying to find the home directory of users on a UNIX (Solaris/AIX) box using

```
echo ~username
```

This does return the home directory for all valid users. For some reason this command also outputs home directory which are non-existent for few users who seem not to have logon access to that server.

For eg. the above command would return below for a non-existent user -

> /home/username

What I expected was

> ~username

as output for a user with no access and that does happen with certain usernames.

This makes me think what could be causing a difference between different users who do not have access to this server. Has this something to do with LDAP?

Nothing I can find in /etc/passwd too.

Comment: what version of ksh are you using?

Comment: apologies - its on Solaris. I have corrected the post.ksh version is  M-11/16/88i.

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with Solaris. Behavior remains same on AIX too.

Comment: Given a "non-existant" user, what does `getent password username` return?

Comment: Yeah that returns the user. So does that mean the home directory path could be a default configuration on the LDAP for non-existent users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getent` and `finger` commands were outputting a default home directory for a non-existent user (not retrieved using ldaplist) because the requests were handled through an intermediate access control mechanism such as Cisco SA Control for role based access control.